# How to hide or show field based on an entry into date field in Powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, date-time, powerapps-forms, hide

In PowerApps custom form I'm looking to hide field B when entry is made into date field A.

I've found plenty of examples for yes/no or dropdown but none for date field.

Thanks, RN

Comment: What is the condition to show/hide fields? Or simply when date field is not blank then hide the field?

Comment: Simple if date is blank hide other field. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide another column when date field is not blank, please refer below steps, if not, please provide more condition information.

1.Make the date column default value as blank() in powerapps.

[image]

2.Select the datacard of another column and change the Visibale function as shown below:

[image]